# Medium error connection with Oauth

Tags: oauth, medium.com-publishing-api

I try to connect my website account on **Medium** (*blog*), via this **URL**:

> https://medium.com/m/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fnetworks%2Fmedium%2Fcallback&scope=basicProfile&response_type=code&client_id=7510274391b7

But, I get this **Medium** error:

> We didn’t understand your request.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the redirect URL that included in the request above doesn't match with the URL in the Medium App created.  Make sure that the redirect URL exact match with the URL in the Medium App corresponding to the URL in the ClientID you are using.

Comment: I've the same problem but the callback URL is good, somes ideas?

Comment: Hello Maxence, I am certain.  when you get the 400 error, check the URL and find out what is the value of the query string parameter redirect_uri=. I am guessing it might be the localhost.... change that to the one you Set in the Medium App. It should redirect to the URL you configured in the App. Keep in mind the Medium as of now does not work with the localhost URL so you will need a proper URL with real domain name to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the redirect uri in our case. We haven't figure out the reason but if you load the same authorise request url again at that 400 message, Medium will just get you through. I know it's a hack, or a bug in their side. who knows.