# Issue in to medium api request

Tags: request, credentials, medium.com-publishing-api

I have problem in to medium api request i have try lot of code but can not solve it this with show error 
"We didn’t understand your request. "
This is my URL for request

```
https://medium.com/m/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxx
&scope=publishPost
&state=CA 
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=mywebsiteurl
```

I am follow this docs
https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Medium error connection with Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786124/medium-error-connection-with-oauth)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved using a URL shortener.

Generate the URL and use it on Medium application config and on `redirect_uri` parameter.